# Passing parameters to component in react through map React

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I'm relatively new to React and Typescript.
I used a map function to create a list, li, in typescript. I tried passing a parameter to a function with info from the mapped object, but it doesn't seem to happen. it seems like the same argument is mapped to all the elements, like so:

```
state = {
        groups: new Array<IGroups>(),
        showGroup: false,
        groupId: 0
    };

showMembers(groupId: number) {

        this.setState({ showGroup: true, groupId: groupId });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.groups.map(group => <li>{group.name} from {group.cityName} <button onClick={() => this.showMembers(group.groupId)}>For members</button></li>)}
                    {this.state.showGroup && <GroupMembers groupId={this.state.groupId}></GroupMembers>}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

the same "groupId" is being passed to the component every time.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [I am not able to reproduce your error](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-williamson-uehrn?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: The code looks fine. It seems like an issue with how the value of `groups` is set. Add a `console.log(this.state.groups)` inside the `render` function before the `return`. What does it show?